# Is it possible to simulate a browser version update?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge, add-on

I'm developing an add-on and I want to test how code that gets executed during the `onInstalled` event behaves after a browser version update.

Is there a way to simulate the browser update event, without waiting when an actual newer version of the browser will be out?

Comment: How about the issue? May I know if you have got any chance to check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082064/is-it-possible-to-simulate-a-browser-version-update/71109057#71109057)? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Comment: No, I haven't tried anything yet. I'm wondering if the event could get triggered through the browser console though!

Answer (score 1):

I don't find any way to simulate browser update event. Here I use Edge as an example. As a workaround, you can [download Edge Canary](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) version to test which updates everyday.

Besides, if your device is Microsoft AD domain joined, you can also configure [this policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-update-policies#rollbacktotargetversion) to roll back Edge version, then update it when you test.